# integrate theme in angular 2 CLI project

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

hello everyone I have purchased one theme and i want to integrate it in my angular 2 project having angular 2 CLI structure.

Comment: Can you give us more info? What kind of theme(Bootstrap, Materialize, ...)?

Comment: its and angular material theme

Comment: Add string with path to styles list in angular-cli.json